# Design Numbers on Dice

Tags: probability, dice

there're 3 dice (1 - 6, numbers can repeat or disappear) A, B, C, they're rolled and compare numbers and larger number win.

If A and B compare A has larger probability to win, B and C B has larger probability to win, C and A C has larger probability to win.

Then how to design the numbers on each dice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [non-transitive dice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice) which has some examples.

Here is an open source project to determine non-transitive dices with additional info and discussions: http://www.devrand.org/2013/01/nontransitive-dice.html?m=1